# Webutil works fine when I run it from Forms Builder, but when I install it on our server, it doesn't work

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-apps

I have used webutil functionality to upload and download files. It works fine when I run it from Oracle Forms Builder. But when I install it on our server I get the following alert when I click on a button to choose a file:

> oracle.forms.webutil.file.filefunctions bean not found. WEBUTIL_FILE.FILE_SELECTION_DIALOG_INT will not work

I have Oracle version 11 on Windows 7. I have not done any changes in webutil.cfg or any other files

I added ?config=webutil at the end of Application Server Url in Forms builder, but don't know if I need to add this config=webutil at the end of the url that I use to call my form menu.

Comment: You have to use the config=webutil instead of your own to test if webutil is functioning correctly

Comment: Where should I add it? on the application server?! could you please provide me more specific information?!

Comment: In the url, something like http://localhost:7779/forms/frmservlet?config=webutil